# Difference between actionPerformed and keyPressed in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

I have started a project in Jframe Netbeans.

One thing which bothers me is this option where on one side I have actionPerformed which contains the action which we do when the key is pressed but again we have another option of key Pressed which does the same.

I know these two cannot perform the same function but what possibly could be the difference?

Comment: ActionPerformed is broader than keyPressed. KeyPressed is only used when the user presses a key. ActionPerformed could be a keypress, but it could also be something else.

Comment: @koen Demonie can you provide the detailed explanation?

Comment: These are explained by the tutorials. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/handling.html

Comment: This link might help you a bit https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`actionPerformed` is called when the user triggers any event. It can be when a user clicks a button, selects a menu item, or presses enter in a text field.

**Documentation:**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

`keyPressed` is more specific and is for when a user presses a key. There are other methods available when implementing a `KeyListener` such as `keyTyped` or `keyReleased` which gives you more control over what the user is doing with the keyboard specifically.

**Documentation:**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

Comment: So, basically actionPerformed is superset and keyPressed is its subset?

Comment: You can think of it that way if it helps. Imagine if you wanted to find out when the user pressed a key and released it using an ActionListener, you would need a lot more logic to find out whether the user pressed or released the key, etc. but the KeyListener gives you that specific information in easy methods.